# How to install apk wear emulator via Android mobile device

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am trying to install wear apk into wear emulator via USB mobile device.

I created the wear apk having the same package name and added the signed wear apk into the raw folder of the device sdk. Also add the XML:

```
<wearableApp package="com.xxx.xx.xx">
<versionCode>6</versionCode>
<versionName>1.0.1</versionName>
<rawPathResId>xxx_wear</rawPathResId>
</wearableApp>
```

and mentioned in the manifest

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
               android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

By using Android wear app in the device, I connected the wear emulator by the mobile device.

But when I try to install/debug apk it is not showing in the wear emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps below to install Android Wear app on emulator through mobile device.

**Start the emulator:**

- Select the virtual device you have created.
- Click the Play button.
- Wait until the emulator initializes and shows the Android Wear home
  screen.

**Pair your handheld with the emulator:**

- On your handheld, install the Android Wear app from Google Play.
- Connect the handheld to your machine through USB.
- Forward the AVD's communication port to the connected handheld device
  (you must do this every time the handheld is connected:

  ```
    adb -d  forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
  ```
- Start the Android Wear app on your handheld device and connect to the
  emulator.
- Tap the menu on the top right corner of the Android Wear app and
  select Demo Cards.
- The cards you select appear as notifications on the home screen of
  the emulator.

Please check [this guidlines](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) for more information!

Comment: I cant find a "Demo cards". Also I just try install skype in my mobile, that time the notification is show on wear emulator and app is listing in wear emulator. @AndiGeeky

Comment: @Binil Surendran: that step is optional step! You are able to install skype on emulator right?

Comment: yes I can. But am not getting why apk debug from the system is installing in mobile but not showing in wear emulator. @AndiGeeky

Comment: @Binil Surendran: Have you forwarded port to 5601?

Comment: yes am use the command " adb -d  forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601" and in the wear app in mobile show as emulator connected @AndiGeeky

Comment: @ Binil Surendran: Are you able to install simple test app from your Android Studio? Try creating new emulator!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130488/discussion-between-binil-surendran-and-andigeeky).